# Different linestyle in same label matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, linestyle

I am generating following figure with matplotlib.

[image]

As you can see its two way graph, from 0 to some value for 1 side, and also same for the other side.
And since both ways have the same labels, with same linestyle, I have only 2 items in legend.

However I would like to change the linestyle for the bottom graph in one item from dashed to line.
So I need something like the following:

[image]

**IS THIS POSSIBLE WITH MATPLOTLIB?**